# Remove object from an array stored in a singleton

Tags: objective-c, macos, algorithm, nsarray

Im working with a singleton to store some data, her's the implementation

```
 static ApplicationData *sharedData = nil;
 @implementation ApplicationData
 @synthesize list;

 + (id)sharedData
 {
  static dispatch_once_t dis;
  dispatch_once(&dis, ^{
     if (sharedData == nil) sharedData = [[self alloc] init];
 });
 return sharedData;
 }

  - (id)init
   {
   if (self = [super init])
   {
     list = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
   }
    return self;
   }
```

if list have less than 3 (2<) object i the app crash with "index 0 beyond bounds for empty array"

```
   // NSMutableArray *anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"", nil];
 while ([[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] lastObject] != nil)
{
    File *file = [[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] lastObject];

    BOOL isDir;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:file.filePath isDirectory:&isDir])
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *tmpDic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:file.fileName,file.filePath,logEnteryErrorfileNotFoundDisplayName,[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]], nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:logShredFileName,logShredFilePath,logShredStatue,logShredDate, nil]];

            [logArray addObject:tmpDic];

            errorOccured = YES;
            [[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] removeLastObject];
            continue;
        }
   ... other code

  }
```

if i use the anArray that work perfectly.
what is the problem  ?

Comment: I used your code in a test app, added 5 objects to list and then ran a modified version of your while loop (that just logs and then removes the last object), and everything worked fine. Are you sure your error is occurring here in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's totally weird, you've probably did something else to achieve this. Why don't you use `- (void)removeAllObjects`?

Maybe you remove objects in the while cycle the last line, ie:

```
while ([[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] count] != 0)
{
    // remove object from list
    // ...
    [[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] removeLastObject];
}
```

And just a note, you don't need to check `if (sharedData == nil)` in `sharedData` as far as it's guaranteed to be executed only once. (unless you do something outside to your static variable, but that's not how it's supposed to be done I believe)

Comment: in fact this is not all the code, my problem is that i have to delete files in a tableview, so "list" contain path files list, and i have to check if the file still accessible ( and save the errors list in a file ), if yes i remove the file from disk and from list, so i cant use removeAllObjects. i update the code.

Comment: thank you for your help, i solve this adding this : if ([[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] count] == 1)
                {
                    [[[ApplicationData sharedData]list] removeAllObjects];}  this is not the cleanest way but that work, and i still dont understand what is the problem :(